# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string memory[3] memory to string memory[] memory requested

Tags: function, arguments, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to pass an array to a smart contract function but getting following error.

```
contract ElectionList {


constructor() public{

 createElection("CHRIST COLLEGE ELECTION", ["amal", "arun", "akhil"]);   

}

function createElection(string memory _title, string[] memory _candidates) public{

    }

 }
```

But getting the following error.

> TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
> implicit conversion from string memory[3] memory to string memory[]
> memory requested.

How to pass a variable length array as a parameter to a function in solidity smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of _candidates array in `createElection()`

Change

```
string[] memory _candidates
```

to

```
string[3] memory _candidates
```